# How to get observations as a list in Stata?

Tags: return, stata

Stata has `r()` macro for values that some commands return (`return list` after the command).

I need similar access to `x` after `list x if y == 1`, but `list` returns only `r(N)`, not values themselves.

Is it possible to get the observations as a local or global macro to refer to it in the code?

Answer (score 3):

Try `levelsof` command to get distinct values. It's the cat's pajamas.

Comment: Thanks! Any solutions for getting a vector if values are not unique?

Comment: I am not aware of one.

Answer (score 2):

One way to save values of *all* observations (i.e. including repeated) is with a loop:

```
clear 
set more off

*----- exmple data -----

sysuse auto
keep rep78

list

*----- what you want -----

forvalues i = 1/`=_N' {
    local myvals `myvals' `=rep78[`i']'
}

display "`myvals'"
```

But more importantly, why do you think you need such a thing?

Comment: Thanks. Why do I need this? To do things like `foreach i in $myvals { ... }`.

Comment: Stata is different in that most commands, when issued, affect all observations. People coming from other languages sometimes don't realize this, and find themselves unnecessarily trying to loop over observations. This is neither natural for the language, nor efficient. On the other hand, use of **global macros** (like in your example) is not recommended unless you are completely sure what you're doing. It can provoke name space clashes. **local macros** are preferred whenever possible.

Comment: In addition to Roberto's excellent points, how would your intended code treat repeated values differently?