# How to create aliases for variables in Stata?

Tags: variables, stata

I want to create a variable `newvar` which value always equals to the value of `oldvar`. So even if `oldvar` gets changed, `newvar` refers to the new value. Commands `g newvar = oldvar` and `clonevar` are insufficient because they do not update `newvar` when `oldvar` has been changed.

Comment: I don't know if this is possible, but like in your [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/27214675/2077064), I ask: why do you need this? Explaining ultimate goals and giving context can help people help you.

Comment: @RobertoFerrer To have handy shortcuts in original datasets. It's possible to do `rename`, but it's a bad idea for many reasons.

Comment: Let me rewind because I think I misunderstood with my first reading. When generating a variable with `gen newvar = oldvar`, there is no perdurable connection between them. You can change `oldvar` and this has no effect over `newvar`. The opposite is also true.

Comment: There's also `clonevar`.

Comment: I'd like it to work it as alias, ie `newvar` equals `oldvar` after changes.

Comment: Yes, I see. Sorry. The first reading was correct after all.

Comment: It may be convenient to have "aliases", but have you considered just saving your original data set with another name and working with that? Then you can `rename` variables to whatever you want. Describing a detailed case where the alias is necessary could help find an answer.

Comment: I think we need concrete examples here.

Comment: @NickCox I reframed the question. Hope it's clear now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no method in Stata of maintaining equality of variables other than changing all variables explicitly in the same way.

If you

```
  gen oldvar = 42 
  gen newvar = oldvar 
  replace oldvar = oldvar + 3
```

then `newvar` remains as it was unless you change it too.

What is possible is that you can store the name of a variable in a local macro.

```
  local myvar "oldvar"
```

Then references to

```
  `myvar'
```

will always be interpreted as references to the current variable `oldvar`.